# Calling the app config method inside ajax response - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing an app using angularjs and this is my first hands on using angular. Although, I have started understanding it and have developed some part of the app but I am stuck at one particular point.

I am trying to implement login functionality, so as the page loads, I am authenticating user and redirecting him to login page. On successful login, I am storing some values of user in one of the config provider.

Now I am using an API which has their own method of authentication and they have expose the ajax method which I can use to authenticate a user.

I have provided a snippet below. What I am primarily doing is using the external API, authenticating the user and once authenticated, I am getting roles associated to that user using another ajax method of the API, called "GetUserDetails".

And inside the response of the "GetUserDetails", I am injecting a provider and setting some values, so I can use this across my app.

The problem  here is the **app.config** method is never called/executded. I mean the ajax request is returning response, and the alert is displayed on my page, but app.config is never executed.

But the same app.config if I call inside the done() of GetUser method, the app.config gets executed and stores values in my provider. But I want the GetuserDetails values also to be stored before I do anything in my app as I want to execute certain functionality based on user.

Below is my function in main.js file

```
 function(angular,angularRoute,app,routes,configService){
    var $html = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]);

    angular.element().ready(function() {

        $.c.authentication.getUser()
            .done(function(response){
                if(response.userName!="anonymous"){

                $.c.ajax({
                    method: "GetUserDetails",

                    parameters: {
                        User: response.user
                    }
                })
                .done(function(res) {
                    alert("I have reached the destination").

                    app.config(['configServiceProvider', function(configServiceProvider){
                    configServiceProvider.setLoginStatus(true);
                    configServiceProvider.setUserName(response.userName);
                    configServiceProvider.setUserObject(response);
                    configServiceProvider.setUserRoleDetails(res);
                    }]);
                })
                .fail(function(res) {
                    alert("Error while getting user roles ."+res);
                });
                    angular.resumeBootstrap([app['name']]);
                }
                else
                {
                    app.config(['configServiceProvider', function(configServiceProvider){
                        configServiceProvider.setLoginStatus(false);
                        configServiceProvider.setUserName(response.userName);


                    }]);

                    //Show Login Screen
                    var url = window.location.href.split("#")[0];
                    window.location.href = url + "#/Login";
                    angular.resumeBootstrap([app['name']]);
                }
            })
            .fail(function(response){
                $rootScope.isLoggedIn=false;
            });

    });
```

Here is my configServiceProvider

```
    define(['../app'],function(app){

return app.provider('configService', function(){
    var options={};
    this.setLoginStatus = function(status){
        //$rootScope.isLoggedIn = status;
        options.isLoggedIn=status;
    };
    this.setPreLoginInfo=function(info){
        options.preLoginInfo=info;
    };
    this.setUserName=function(name){
        options.username=name;
    }

    this.setUserObject = function(userObject) {
        options.userObject = userObject;
    }

    this.setUserRoleDetails = function(userRoleDetails) {
        options.userRoleDetails = userRoleDetails;
    }

    this.$get=[function(){
        if(!options){

        }
        return options;
    }];
});
```

})

Can anyone please explain me what's going wrong here or what I am missing ?

Also, is there any alternative to achieve the same functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

No luck in figuring out why the above scenario was not working. Since I had already spent lot of time behind this, I have found a workaround to achieve the same with the use of services.